# Python3 | TypeError: 'AsyncRequest' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Работаю с grequests в 3 питоне. Вызывает ошибку `TypeError: 'AsyncRequest' object is not iterable`. Код:

```
import grequests
u = 'http://shost-craft.su'


params = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
rs = grequests.post(u, data=params)
responses_list = grequests.map(rs)
print(responses_list[0].text)
print(rs)
```

Не знаю почему вызывает, вроде бы все правильно. 
Можно **post** методом, **get** одно и то же.

Comment: ВСЕГДА выкладывайте ПОЛНЫЙ traceback исключения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grequests.map` предназначена для конкурентной обработки нескольких запросов и получения их ответов, поэтому вам и выдается ошибка о том, что данный метод применяется к итерируемому объекту. Чтобы ваш код заработал, можно `rs` обернуть, например, в список:

```
import grequests
u = 'http://shost-craft.su'


params = {'a':'b', 'c':'d'}
rs = grequests.post(u, data=params)
responses_list = grequests.map([rs])
print(responses_list[0].text)
print(rs)
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)